# Erro ao carregar arquivo XML de endereço web

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Tenho um jogo flash onde carrego as palavras através de um ficheiro XML ou seja:

```
var carregaPalavras:XML = new XML();
carregaPalavras.ignoreWhite = true;
carregaPalavras.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        parsePalavras();
    } else {
        guessWord_txt.text = "Ocorreu um erro!";
    }
};
carregaPalavras.load("palavras.xml");
```

Agora pretendia dar uma mais valia a isto, e carregar as palavras através de um URL que tenho. Já experimentei da seguinte forma mas não carrega:

```
carregaPalavras.load("http://meusite.com/palavras.xml");
```

Já tentei assim, em AS3, mas também da erro:

```
var myXML:XML;
var carregaPalavras:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
carregaPalavras.load(new URLRequest("http://meusite.com/palavras.xml"));
```

Comment: Qual o erro que acontece?

Comment: Acabei de editar acima, basicamente descobri que estou a implementar em AS2, e não As3 portanto o codigo acima não dá.
Há algum load url para AS2?

Comment: Testei o primeiro exemplo em AS2 e funcionou corretamente... Qual o erro que aparece? Recomendaria você utilizar ActionScript 3.0, isso não é possível?

Comment: Sim é, mas a converter depois da me erro "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Void."

Comment: O 1º exemplo, ou seja carregar localmente funciona bem. Mas eu quero alojar o xml no servidor web e nao consigo ir buscar atraves do url

Answer (score 1):

### ActionScript 2.0 para 3.0

A linguagem `ActionScript 2.0 / 1.0` é limitada, por possuir poucas classes, partindo do princípio de que fora criada apenas para suprir algumas ações do Flash, inclusive não é orientada a eventos, o que torna difícil o tratamento de erros. Praticamente podemos dizer que, em relação ao `ActionScript 3.0`, de parecido apenas o nome.

Os erros ocorrem pois muitas ações que você realizava em AS2 não são nada parecidas com AS3, então, ao converter seu projeto para uma versão diferente, realmente o conflito irá acontecer. Isso sem falar que a versão 2.0 da linguagem não tem suporte desde 2006, quando ocorreu o lançamento da versão 3.0.

[Neste link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) do wikipedia você pode encontrar mais informações.

### Código AS2

Em relação à sua pergunta, o código para carregar um arquivo XML no `ActionScript 2.0` é exatamente como abaixo:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(); //Cria o objeto XML
//Define a função que será executada ao carregar o arquivo
xml.onLoad = function(resposta) { 
    if(resposta) {
       trace("Carregou XML"); //Mostra no Output que carregou o arquivo xml
       trace(xml);
    }
    else {
       trace("Erro ao carregar XML!");
    }
}

//Ao ocorrer um evento do servidor, como um erro, ele executará esta função:
xml.onData = function(resposta) {
    trace("Resposta do servidor: ");
    trace(resposta);
}    

xml.load("arquivo.xml"); //Executa a ação para carregar. Qualquer URI, seja externa ou local, é aceita.
```

Os erros que podem acontecer serão tratados pelo método `onData`. Você pode acessar a referencia da linguagem 2.0 [neste link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html).

### Código AS3

O código para carregar o XML em `ActionScript 3.0` é um pouco mais aguçado, porém, mais funcional com relação à tratamento de eventos.

```
var xml:XML; //Cria a referência ao objeto XML
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); //Responsável por carregar arquivos
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("arquivo.xml"); //Objeto que contém e trata URLs

urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, carregouXML);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, erroXML);

//Evento ao carregar o XML com sucesso!
function carregouXML(e:Event):void {
    xml = new XML(urlLoader.data);
    trace("Carregou XML");
    trace(xml);
}

//Erro ao carregar XML
function erroXML(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
   trace("Erro ao carregar XML: "+e);
}
```

Os erros podem ser tratados pelos eventos `IOErrorEvent` e `SecurityError`. Você pode acessar a referência da linguagem 3.0 [neste link](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).

### Conclusão

Se a sua intenção for realizar a mudança de versões do ActionScript, tenha em mente que o código inteiro do seu jogo terá que ser adaptado. Particularmente recomendo que você utilize a versão 3.0, mais atual, com mais recursos Web, utilizado em Flex e Flash e com suporte Adobe AIR Desktop e Mobile.

Agora, caso a conversão não seja possível, trate os erros com os métodos citados e procure revisar algumas ações na referência de código nos links da Adobe.

Comment: Convertendo para AS3 da me erro nas seguintes linhas onde tenho "function parsePalavras():Void {" e o erro que dá é "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Void." Pesquisei soluções, tentei colocar imports mas mantem-se o problema

Comment: `Void` é uma palavra reservada do ActionScript 2.0, porém, as palavras reservadas no ActionScript 3.0 agora são escritas em minúsculas! Mude para `void`, em letra minúscula. Esse erro geralmente acontece quando ele não encontra uma definição para uma classe/objeto/variável que você está utilizando.

Comment: resolveu! obrigado, surgiu foi outro do loadvars
tenho o codigo "TopicoInicio.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
 if (success) {
  startScreen_mc.message_txt.text = Benvindo1+this.meuTopico+Benvindo2;
 } else {
  startScreen_mc.message_txt.text = "Ocorreu um erro!";
 }
};"

Comment: Sim, no AS3, métodos como `onLoad` não são mais utilizados. Procure utilizar o exemplo de **Código AS3** na resposta!

Comment: Corrigindo o erro é especifico em: "var TopicoInicio:LoadVars = new LoadVars();" no Loadvars

Comment: Este link pode te ajudar! http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/01/27/as2-to-as3/as2-%E2%86%92-as3-loadvars-as3-equivalent/

Comment: não estou a conseguir resolver, basicamente eu faço um load de um ficheiro TXT (que apenas tem uma palavra, sobre o tema do jogo)

var Benvindo1:String = "Bem vindo ao Jogo da Forca! O tema é sobre ";
var Benvindo2:String = ". Pressione o botão JOGAR para inicar.";
var TopicoInicio:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
TopicoInicio.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
 if (success) {
  startScreen_mc.message_txt.text = Benvindo1+this.meuTopico+Benvindo2;
 } else {
  startScreen_mc.message_txt.text = "Ocorreu um erro!";
 }
};
TopicoInicio.load("topico.txt");

Comment: Sim, está claro que você não entendeu muito bem a diferença entre AS2 e AS3. O problema é que você ainda continua a utilizar métodos da versão 2.0. Se você converteu seu projeto para versão 3.0, nenhum destes métodos irá funcionar. O objeto que faz o load de arquivos na versão 3.0 se chama [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html). Como dito na resposta, o AS3 é orientado à eventos, então, você tem que utilizar o método `addEventListener`, para o evento `Event.COMPLETE`, para "escutar" que o arquivo foi carregado com êxito.